# MYSQL SLEEP inside EXISTS block

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

When I execute this SQL code on a SQL server:

```
SELECT SLEEP(3);
```

The server sleeps for 3 seconds. But, when I execute this code:

```
SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE EXISTS(SELECT SLEEP(3));
```

The server immediately prints the table 'costumers' without waiting for 3 seconds... Is there an explanation for the SLEEP function just returning without waiting for the specified duration when it is called from an EXISTS block? The same happens with the BENCHMARK function in this code:

```
SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE EXISTS(SELECT BENCHMARK(100, MD5(1)))
```

I need to execute the 'SLEEP' function in this specific structure because this is used in a SQL injection exercise, more precisely a blind SQL injection exercise.

Also, if you know of another way to write a MYSQL statement which make the server wait, that would be helpful.

Comment: Sub-query probably optimized as always "TRUE", and skipped.

Answer (score 3):

The query optimizer apparently determines that `SELECT SLEEP(3)` always returns `TRUE`, so it removes the code.

This query sleeps:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT SLEEP(3) UNION SELECT 1);
```

The union is apparently too complex for the MySQL optimizer to figure out, so it executes it. In fact, using `EXPLAIN` on this query takes 3 seconds -- it realizes that the subquery doesn't depend on any tables, so it executes it while determining the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to be stuck with a

```
SELECT SLEEP(3); SELECT * FROM customers;
```

combo.